# PHP file input code assistance

Tags: php, forms, upload

I have a form which has 2 file input fields. I have a PHP script which nicely handles the upload of the files - but what I am missing is the ability to get back the filename values from the form after the upload is complete. The code is below.

I am thinking maybe it might be easier to adapt this code to make it specific to upload the files of each specified file input - then I can get the file name back from easily?

e.g. so have 2 blocks of code to upload and store the file name value of inputs - input1 and input2 for example...?

Any ideas?

```
// initialize output;
$output = true;

// valid extensions
$ext_array = array('pdf', 'txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'rtf', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'eps', 'svg', 'gif', 'ai');

// create unique path for this form submission
//$uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/';

// you can create some logic to automatically
// generate some type of folder structure here.
// the path that you specify will automatically
// be created by the script if it doesn't already
// exist.

// UPLOAD TO FOLDER IN /ASSETS/UPLOADS/ WITH ID OF THE PARENT PROJECT FOLDER RESOURCE 

// Get page ID
// $pageid = $modx->resource->get('id');
// $uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/'.$pageid.'/';

// Get parent page title
$parentObj = $modx->resource->getOne('Parent');
$parentpageid = $parentObj->get('pagetitle');
$uploadpath = 'assets/uploads/'.$parentpageid.'/';

// get full path to unique folder
$target_path = $modx->config['base_path'] . $uploadpath;

// get uploaded file names:
$submittedfiles = array_keys($_FILES);


// loop through files
foreach ($submittedfiles as $sf) {

// Get Filename and make sure its good.
$filename = basename( $_FILES[$sf]['name'] );

// Get file's extension
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext = mb_strtolower($ext); // case insensitive

// is the file name empty (no file uploaded)
if($filename != '') {

// is this the right type of file?
if(in_array($ext, $ext_array)) {

    // clean up file name and make unique
    $filename = mb_strtolower($filename); // to lowercase
    $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename); // spaces to underscores
    $filename = date("Y-m-d_G-i-s_") . $filename; // add date & time

    // full path to new file
    $myTarget = $target_path . $filename;

    // create directory to move file into if it doesn't exist
    mkdir($target_path, 0755, true);

    // is the file moved to the proper folder successfully?
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$sf]['tmp_name'], $myTarget)) {
        // set a new placeholder with the new full path (if you need it in subsequent hooks)
        $modx->setPlaceholder('fi.'.$sf.'_new', $myTarget);
        // set the permissions on the file
        if (!chmod($myTarget, 0644)) { /*some debug function*/ }

    } else {
        // File not uploaded
        $errorMsg = 'There was a problem uploading the file.';
        $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
        $output = false; // generate submission error
    }

} else {
    // File type not allowed
    $errorMsg = 'Type of file not allowed.';
    $hook->addError($sf, $errorMsg);
    $output = false; // generate submission error
}

// if no file, don't error, but return blank
} else {
$hook->setValue($sf, '');
}

}

return $output;
```